# Share wifi to multiple ethernet clients

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have 3 machines all running Windows 10 that I need to have internet, but because of latency I need them to have a wired connection to each other.

One of the machines has wifi and 2 ethernet jacks.

One of the others has wifi and ethernet. The other only has ethernet.
I'd like to be able to share the wifi between all 3 machines. I can't figure out how to set this up so that I have internet and a wired connection between all 3 machines.

Comment: Maybe get a router?

Comment: If all have Ethernet, why not connect all 3 to the router via Ethernet?

Comment: Sorry, we only have wifi. I should have mentioned that. 

I was hoping to find a solution without just buying a switch.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a Bridge.

You need to connect one of the computers to the wireless network, and then Bridge the wireless and wired network connections on that computer.

This allows that computer to communicate over the wireless network, and then share the internet connection over the wired connections.

I don't recall if you have to set up static IPs, but I don't think you do.

I also don't recall if you can bridge one wireless with two different ethernet ports.

This uses abilities already built-in to Windows and requires no extra software or hardware.

Comment: If the Wi-Fi access point doesn't support 4-way MAC addresses, AKA WDS, then a bridge won't work. You'll have to revert to setting up routing in layer 3 and having one of the computers connect to the Wi-Fi network, and have it serve as the router to provide access through its Ethernet port to the other two. This requires that you have access to configure the Wi-Fi router to add your new local LAN address range to its routing table where your Wi-Fi connected computer serves as the gateway. Some cheap Wi-Fi access points don't adding support custom routes.

Comment: Also, there is nothing stopping you from networking the three together with wires and using a separate IP address range, while connecting to Wi-Fi at the same time. The 3rd computer that doesn't have Wi-Fi won't be able to connect to anything other than the other two computers though.